# Finding the longest path(by lenght) in an undirected weighted cylic graph with two conditions

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

I downloaded a map of a city, where crossroads are nodes(I even have the exact coordinates of the nodes) and I have the paths between nodes with the length as a whole number.
I need to find the longest path, that can be found through an algorithm, in this graph, I can start and end where ever i want, but I have two conditions. I can visit a node only once and  I cant see any other street twice (that is, if you take any two vertices of the road that do not follow each other closely, then there will be no edge between them in the graph)

I´ve tried to divide the map into multiple trees, where it is possible to find the longest path, then I connected these trees and calculated the length, but it isn´t enough.

Do you have any ideas on how to solve this problem?

Input may look like this:
3(number of nodes) 3(number of roads)
1(node) 49.485993 16.5789384 (coordinates)
2 49.485994 16.5789345
3 49.485990 16.5789368
1(node) 3(node) 50(lenght in meters)
1 2 90
2 3 110

Here I tried to draw the second condition

[image]

Comment: I do not understand this condition _ I can't see any other street twice_. Please [edit] and clarify. An example would make it easier. Also how did you find the longest path in a sub-graph ?

Comment: To me it sounds like figure out the longest path which Hamiltonian as well as Euler. Should add an input and output example so that community understand what exactly is expected.

Comment: @c0der  I tried to draw the second condition as I am not able to explain it in english sufficiently. In the sub-graph I made a tree like datastructure and there I tried to find the longest path

Comment: @ShridharRKulkarni I added it into the post, hope it helps

Comment: Does the second condition mean that a neighbor of a visited node is also considered visited ? Or is it direction-dependent? Did you manage to find the longest path on a sub-graph ?

Comment: @c0der Yes, a neighbor of a visited node is also considered visited, that describes it well. I managed to find a long path around (400 000 meters), but i know i can get up to 3 500 000 meters and with sub-graphs i´m not even remotly close to this.

Comment: _then I connected these trees_ I assume this is wrong.  Are you able to find the longest path in a sub-graph? If so what is limiting you from doing in on the whole graph?  Run a [depth first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) on the entire graph, mark neighbors as visited when you 'getNeighbors`.  For more help post [mre]